# Same Shadows Remaining on Duplicated Object

Tags: shadows

I'm new on blender 2.93 on Windows 7 64-bit and it is amazing! But i was wondering what causes this shadow issue? whether i use array modifier or straight out duplicate the road object and lay it side by side, the same shadow effect remains on the duplicated object as seen in picture. Is this a bug?

PS: Only diffuse/color map was RGB, the rest were non-color but it also happens when i removed all materials/textures and just rendered as a solid

PS: i was able to finish my animation thanks to the cool pips on blender stack exchange! here's the result https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J1Dra4LC8s

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard too see from your node setup, but are your Normal and Displacement maps both set to _non-color_  color space (not sRGB)? Also, what Strength is your Normal Map set to?

Comment: please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi thank you for your response! i also tried removing all materials/textures, rendered just as a solid and i still get the same shadow problem, i uploaded the file road.blend at https://pasteall.org/blend/078f19b273a046019b89d9acc439142e

Comment: hi guys thank you for taking the time to help me out, it was resolved by ticking auto-smooth in world properties > normals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is definitely a problems with your normals.

always check the following:

- your normals are set to "non-color"
- if your normals are made for DX11 then you will have to invert the green channel. do it with a separate RGB node, this ways you can isolate the G channel and then use an invert node. finally combine them with a combine RGB node and plug it to your normal.

if the problem persist then check your object normals by doing the following:

- in edit mode select all vertex and with spacebar search "recalculate outside" this will recalculate all normals to point in the correct orientation.
- if after this your object looks smooth, then go to properties>mesh>Normals and check autosmooth

Comment: hello thank you for your response, only my diffuse/color map uses RGB, all the rest are non-color. but it also happens even when i remove all materials/textures and render just as a solid. here is the file https://pasteall.org/blend/078f19b273a046019b89d9acc439142e

Comment: yes you are right, it was related to the normals. It works when i tick the checkbox auto-smooth in world properties > normals. but that is so weird. if the "right click > shade smooth" requires this checkbox to be ticked then why doesn't it just automatically do this so it won't create this weird "bug"?

Comment: Well it's not a bug. The thing with autosmooth is that you have to use it with objects that have sharp edges. For example let say you want the round side of a cylinder smooth but also to keep sharp edges on the top and bottom lid, that's when you use the autosmooth. But if you use the autosmooth with some organic shape, let say a human, you will get weird normals, some faces will get flat shade and it will look bad. Also, a good way of controlling autosmooth is to add the "weight edit" modifier, this will give you some extra controls over the sharpness.